# Dynamically sorting an array of objects in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

A drop-down list is implemented in which the active class is added when an item in the items array is selected. Everything works, but you need to display the selected item first in the list, and not in any order. I tried this approach `const newItems = [selectedAccount, ... items]` and then map newItems, but the problem is that then the selected item is displayed twice in the drop-down list.

```
type TAccountListProps= {
  isVisible: boolean;
  items: Accounts.Account[];
  selectedAccount: Accounts.Account | null;
  onSelect: (id: string) => void;
  onToggle: (value: boolean) => void;
};

export const AccountList: React.FunctionComponent<TAccountListProps> = ({
  isVisible,
  items,
  selectedAccount,
  onSelect,
  onToggle
}) => {
  if (!isVisible) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="account-list">

      {items.map((item) => {

        const isSelected = item.id == selectedAccount?.id;

        return (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            className={classnames(
              'account-list__account',
              { 'account-list__account_active': isSelected }
            )}
            onClick={() => {
              onSelect(item.id);
              onToggle(false);
            }}
          >
            <div className="account-list__icon-block">
              <CardOutline className="account-list__icon" />
              <div className="account-list__info">
                <div className="account-list__name">
                  Расчётный счёт
                </div>
                <div className="account-list__number">
                  {formatAccountNumber(item.num.value)}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {item.balance && (
              <div className="account-list__balance">
                <span>{item.balance}</span>
                <span className="account-list__currency">
                  &nbsp;
                  {CurrencySigns.Rub}
                </span>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So filter out the selected item:

```
const newItems = [
  selectedAccount,
  ...items.filter(item.id != selectedAccount?.id)
];
```

Comment: Yes, it really helped me. Thank!